# How to register a custom keyboard shortcut for a windows application

Tags: windows, registry, keyboard-shortcuts

I want to create a windows utility application, which can be called anytime from within any other application using a keyboard shortcut, e.g.:

• <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>

• <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>

• <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>

• <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>

• <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>

**What key combinations can I use and how to setup those in the windows registry?**

(If the shortcut is used by an other application, it should of course not work.)

Comment: Are you asking to set those shortcuts programatically or manually?

Comment: What's STRG?  Is this the same as CTRL?

Comment: STRG is the german name for CTRL :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An option for doing that programatically when your application start is calling this Windows API:

```
RegisterHotKey(IntPtr hwnd, int id, int fsModifiers, int vk);
```

And to unregister call this API:

```
UnregisterHotKey(IntPtr hwnd, int id);
```

Both exist in `user32` APIs

[http://www.pinvoke.net/search.aspx?search=RegisterHotKey&namespace=[All]](http://www.pinvoke.net/search.aspx?search=RegisterHotKey&namespace=%5BAll%5D)

Comment: Works for Programmatic shortcut key assignment

Answer (score 1):

If your application (or a shortcut to it) is available on your desktop, you can right-click to get the context menu, select Properties, and enter the Shortcut Key there.  Simply click in the Shortcut Key text field, and press the desired shortcut key.

I've assigned <kbd>WIN</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> to my calculator, and <kbd>WIN</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> to my volume control.

Comment: Works for Manual shortcut key assignment

Comment: That's funny. This only seems to work for 'native' applications. As every application I've made in winforms c# don't have that setting in the properties dialog when you right click the file on desktop

Comment: Been wondering [over on SuperUser](http://superuser.com/q/424782/69392) wether there's a centralized storage for those hotkeys. I would suspect that to be in the registry. Now you seem to be implying that the set of shortcuts "on your desktop" is scanned for hotkey mappings. Any pointers for more details?

Answer (score 1):

If you need more advanced scenario to what the shell shortcut offer, you should start with reading [Win32 Hooks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms997537.aspx) and [Hooks Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632589(VS.85).aspx).

More specifically, you need to add a `WH_KEYBOARD` hook using the [`SetWindowsHookEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644990(VS.85).aspx) function. You also need to unhook through [`UnhookWindowsHookEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644993(VS.85).aspx) when you are done.

There's an old article from Dino Esposito how to do [Windows Hooks in .NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc188966.aspx) through some Win32 interop.

Comment: Works for Programmatic shortcut key assignment

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid this isnt something you can do by simply setting values in the registry, it is as has been indicated in other answers necessary to call some windows API routines to achieve this.