# Changing Default Windows Keyboard Shortcuts

Tags: c#, .net, windows, vb.net, winapi

Is there a way to change default Windows keyboard shortcuts like <kbd>CTRL + C</kbd>, <kbd>CTRL + X</kbd> etc. to my desired shortcuts like  <kbd>CTRL + J</kbd>, <kbd>CTRL + Q</kbd> etc. in .NET ?

I can register the new hotkey easily with [RegisterHotkey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646309%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). I just need to unregister the hotkeys Windows has registered and add their functionality in the new hotkey.

Comment: Are you talking about actual shortcuts for the Explorer (the "file manager")?  Or those shortcuts in general windows applications?  If the latter, that ultimately depends on the applications but those are usually hard coded.

Comment: Maybe it'll help.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/598837/how-to-register-a-custom-keyboard-shortcut-for-a-windows-application

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I understand exactly what you want to do, so not sure if these suggestions are helpful.

You can use the instructions on [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb521407%28v=winembedded.5%29.aspx) to disable keyboard shortcuts.

You could then use the instructions in [these](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7294/Processing-Global-Mouse-and-Keyboard-Hooks-in-C) [articles](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/toub/archive/2006/05/03/589423.aspx) to create a global keyboard hook that could listen for the keyboard combinations. And then you could do whatever action you need in response to those events.

Answer (score -1):

You may try following code to customized your Hot Keys.

```
private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Alt && e.KeyCode.ToString() == "F")
        {

            this.KeyPreview = false;
            MessageBox.Show("Alt Key and F Key Pressed");
        } 
    }
```